# Como limitar números decimais em Python?

Tags: python, float

Como faço para formatar a quantidade de casas decimais de um número decimal em Python?

Por exemplo, eu quero exibir apenas duas casas decimais do seguinte número:

```
numero_decimal = 3.141592653589793
```

Como eu poderia transformar esse número para `3.14`?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### Arredondando

Se for arredondar:

```
round(3.141592653589793, 2)
```

Que é o que acontece quando você faz algo assim.

```
"%.2f" % 3.141592653589793
```

### Truncando

Neste caso já precisa de mais cuidado, pois a falta de uma função dedicada obriga a compor uma solução manual.

Essa função simples atende bem no dia a dia:

```
def trunc(num, digits):
   sp = str(num).split('.')
   return '.'.join([sp[0], sp[:digits]])
```

Este aqui funciona em 2 e 3 e leva em consideração notação exponencial, para cenários mais complexos:

```
def truncate(f, n):
    '''Truncates/pads a float f to n decimal places without rounding'''
    s = '{}'.format(f)
    if 'e' in s or 'E' in s:
        return '{0:.{1}f}'.format(f, n)
    i, p, d = s.partition('.')
    return '.'.join([i, (d+'0'*n)[:n]])
```

Códigos aproveitados daqui:

> https://stackoverflow.com/q/783897/916193

**Nota:** para quem não sabe a diferença:

- Ao arredondar `3.19999` para 2 decimais o resultado é `3.20`;
- Ao truncar`3.19999` para 2 decimais o resultado é `3.19`.

Answer (score 11):

No Python 3 tem um novo recurso que torna essa tarefa bem mais fácil, é o `.format()` que você vai usar na hora de printar o resultado na tela.

Para printar o seu comado com apenas 2 casas decimais é só fazer o seguinte:

```
pi = 3.141592653589793
print('O valor de pi formatado é {:.2f}'.format(pi))
```

Primeiro atribuí pi a uma variável float e depois printei com o `.format` dizendo que queria 2 casas decimais após a vírgula.

Outro jeito é usar os f strings que permitem fazer todo o necessário dentro do próprio print e sem o `format` (eu prefiro esse jeito).

```
pi = 3.141592653589793
print(f'O valor de pi formatado é {pi:.2f}')
```

Answer (score 6):

Uma outra maneira de formatar de uma maneira muito semelhante é com o f-Strings:

```
pi = 3.141592653589793
print(f'O resultado de PI é {pi:.2f}')
```

Note o uso do 'f' antes da mensagem que virá e também a variável 'pi' que vai diretamente dentro das chaves junto com a formatação de 2 casas decimais depois da vírgula

Answer (score 3):

Eu fiz usando o `round`.

Exemplo:

```
A = 3/9
valor = round(A,3)
print (valor)
```

Ou você pode fazer direto:

```
A = round(3/9,3)
print (A)
```

Sendo o 3 a quantidade de casas decimais que você quer manter.

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer **truncamento** uma forma simples:

```
n1= 1.9999999999999

t =3 # Numero de casas

d = int(n1 * 10**t)/10**t

print('Truncado', d)

print('Arredondado', round(n1,t))
```