# Como imprimir as informações no formato de tabela em python?

Tags: python-3.x

Eu gostaria de imprimir os resultados no formato de tabela conforme imagem em anexo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No código que estou fazendo é pra literalmente reproduzir o sistema de financiamento acima.
Só que quando eu vou testar, eles imprimem um abaixo do outro e eu não sei como fazer pra imprimir um ao lado do outro como na imagem.

Comment: E como está fazendo? Qual foi a saída obtida?

Comment: Eu imprimo um abaixo do outro.

Comment: Numero: Valores. Saldo valores etc... Aí eu quero imprimir um ao lado do outro como na imagem.

Comment: Mostre o código

Comment: Pode usar essa biblioteca do python (Pretty Table), nesse link tem uma introdução a ela: https://www.vooo.pro/insights/python-pretty-table/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basta você utilizar o método `format` da *string*:

```
>>> '{:>13,.2f}'.format(100000)
'   100,000.00'
```

Onde:

- As chaves, `{}`, definem um grupo referente aos parâmetros de `format`;
- Os dois pontos, `:`, iniciam as regras de formatação do valor;
- O sinal de maior, `>`, define que o alinhamento à direita;
- O número 13, `13` mesmo, define o espaço total da saída;
- A vírgula, `,`, representa o caractere separador dos milhares;
- O ponto, `.`, inicia as regras de formatação da parte decimal;
- O número 2, `2` mesmo, define que haverá apenas 2 casas decimais;
- A letra f, `f`, define que a entrada será um tipo *float*;

Leia-se, então, `{:>13,.2f}` como: formate este número *float* com 2 casas decimais, utilizando a vírgula como separador dos milhares, alinhado à direita em um espaço de 13 caracteres.

Supondo que você possui cada linha em uma lista, poderia fazer:

```
>>> linha = [1, 100000.00, 9282.21, 8333.33, 948.88, 91666.67]
>>> print('{:^6}   {:>13,.2f}   {:>9,.2f}   {:>11,.2f}   {:>9,.2f}   {:>11,.2f}'.format(*linha))
'  1         100,000.00    9,282.21      8,333.33      948.88     91,666.67'
```

Seguindo o raciocínio, com poucas complementos ao código acima, você facilmente produz a saída:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Número   Saldo Inicial   Prestação   Amortização     Juros     Saldo Final
------   -------------   ---------   -----------   ---------   -----------
  1         100,000.00    9,282.21      8,333.33      948.88     91,666.67
  1         100,000.00    9,282.21      8,333.33      948.88     91,666.67
  1         100,000.00    9,282.21      8,333.33      948.88     91,666.67
  1         100,000.00    9,282.21      8,333.33      948.88     91,666.67
  1         100,000.00    9,282.21      8,333.33      948.88     91,666.67
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Em versões 3.6+ do Python existem as chamadas *f-strings* que facilitam esta formatação de dados. As regras são as mesmas, mas ao invés de utilizar o método `format`, você informa o nome das variáveis na própria formatação, deixando, assim, o código mais legível. O nome *f-string* é devido ao prefixo `f` que deve existir junto à *string*:

```
>>> linha = [1, 100000.00, 9282.21, 8333.33, 948.88, 91666.67]
>>> numero, saldo_inicial, prestacao, amortizacao, juros, saldo_final = linha
>>> print(f'{numero:^6}   {saldo_inicial:>13,.2f}   {prestacao:>9,.2f}   {amortizacao:>11,.2f}   {juros:>9,.2f}   {saldo_final:>11,.2f}') 
'  1         100,000.00    9,282.21      8,333.33      948.88     91,666.67'
```

E, finalmente, como são dados monetários, não descarte a opção de formatar via `locale`:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_BR')
>>> locale.format('%.2f', 100000.00, grouping=True)
'100.000,00'
```

Veja também `locale.currency`.

Outras leituras:

- [Como limitar números decimais em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/176243/5878)
- [Formatação de caracteres](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/262184/5878)

Comment: Além do "print" com o format - vale a pena mencionar as f-strings - bem mais simples que usar o format.

Comment: Vou estudar isso aí e tentar reproduzir. Até o final da tarde venho aqui dá um retorno.