# Conversão de float para str sem perder as duas casas decimais e mudando o separador decimal

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatação

No Python, preciso converter um `float` para string e substituir o ponto por vírgula, sem perder as duas casas decimais. Já tentei de várias formas, mas não consegui.

Ao fazer:

```
>>> str(10.00).replace('.',',')
```

O retorno é:

```
'10,0'
```

Mas preciso que seja:

```
'10,00'
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer isso de forma prática?
Ou seja, mantendo o padrão de formatação com duas casas decimais após a vírgula.

Pensei em criar uma função, que iria avaliar a quantidade de itens após a vírgula, e se houvesse um, concatenaria com zero, se houvesse dois números decimais, não faria nada. Mas acredito que existe um jeito mais 'inteligente' de fazer isso no python, talvez algo semelhante ao que é feito em alguns bancos de dados, exemplo: `to_char(10.00, '9999999999D99')`.

Comment: Acho que pode ajudar: [Como limitar números decimais em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/176243/125486).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você está utilizando **IDLE** pode utilizar o seguinte código

```
>>> str(f'{float(10.00):.2f}').replace('.', ',')
```

Neste caso a saída será:

```
'10,00'
```

Agora se você quiser implementar um script pode utilizar o seguinte código:

```
n = float(input('Digite um valor real: '))
print(str(f'{n:.2f}').replace('.', ','))
```

**OBSERVAÇÃO**

Neste último caso a saída também será do tipo **string**. Se você pedir para exibir o tipo de variável será exibido o tipo `str`.

Answer (score 2):

Uma opção é usar [`locale.format`](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html#locale.format) (até Python 3.6), ou [`locale.format_string`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.format_string) (a partir do Python 3.7, pois nesta versão `locale.format` se tornou *deprecated*):

```
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.utf8')
print(locale.format_string('%.2f', 10.00)) # 10,00
```

Primeiro eu uso [`setlocale`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.setlocale) para indicar que quero usar o *locale* `pt_BR` (Português do Brasil), no qual o separador decimal é a vírgula. Depois, basta indicar o formato `%.2f`, que diz para formatar o número com duas casas decimais.

---

O interessante deste módulo é que permite um controle maior sobre a formatação, que eu acho mais adequado do que ficar fazendo `replace`. Por exemplo, você também pode indicar se vai ter ou não o separador de milhares, caso o valor seja maior que 1000:

```
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.utf8')

# sem separador de milhares
print(locale.format_string('%.2f', 12345.00)) # 12345,00

# com separador de milhares
print(locale.format_string('%.2f', 12345.00, True)) # 12.345,00
```

Além de poder formatar como um valor monetário (não sei se era essa a intenção):

```
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.utf8')

# sem separador de milhares
print(locale.currency(12345.00)) # R$ 12345,00

# com separador de milhares
print(locale.currency(12345.00, grouping=True)) # R$ 12.345,00
```

---

O detalhe é que este módulo usa bibliotecas em C para obter o formato referente ao *locale*, segundo a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html):

> *The `locale` module is implemented on top of the `_locale` module, which in turn uses an ANSI C locale implementation if available.*

Então o *locale* `pt_BR` deve estar instalado/configurado no sistema operacional para que funcione. Caso contrário, a alternativa é usar `replace` mesmo, conforme sugerido na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/486547/112052).